# Paging mode in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

As far as I understand paging will be carried out on adresses if they exceed the defined size. Currently we experience a paging, but not on known addresses (queues). It seems like it is an internal queue from ActiveMQ? Is it possible to understand what kind of address ActiveMQ is paging here?

```
WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222038: Starting paging on address '$.artemis.internal.my-cluster.fec50662-55c7-11eb-91d1-005056903119'; size is currently: 25,238,532 bytes; max-size-bytes: -1; global-size-bytes: 524,357,417
```

This is important for us, because we have analyzed that this paging causing the inability for the messages in our queues to be consumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address named `$.artemis.internal.my-cluster.fec50662-55c7-11eb-91d1-005056903119`, and the related queue, are used for intra-cluster communication. When messages need to be moved from one node to another they are sent to this address and then forwarded to another broker by the internal cluster bridge.

Given the log message I would surmise that you've reached the `global-size-bytes` which is calculated by adding up the bytes from *all* addresses. You might consider increasing your `global-max-size` in `broker.xml`.

You say that this paging is preventing your consumers from consuming messages. However, it's also worth noting that paging is typically *caused* by consumers not consuming messages, not the other way around. When consumers slow down or stop then messages build up in the broker and it has no choice but to begin paging. Therefore you would likely see both of these things simultaneously which could lead to misattribution.

Comment: our <global-max-size> is currently 500Mb.  Yes, we are considering increasing this value.  A question: why does not the value of 'size is currently' increase 500Mb? size is currently: 25,238,532 bytes; global-size-bytes: 524,357,417

Comment: <global-max-size> is the size pro Broker or pro Cluster?

Comment: `global-max-size` is enforced per broker, not per cluster. Could you create a new post with your other question? I think it's too much to explain in the comments here.